# Getting error "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute" in FB Canvas App even after I've hardcoded the absolute Canvas URI

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have read many posts getting this same error and I have tried many combinations of app settings as well as code. I have posted both my app settings and PHP code below. I am pretty new to both FB integration and PHP so I could be doing something obviously stupid. Please help and tell me what it is!

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('*myappid*','*myappsecret*');
  /**
   * Returns the JSON encoded POST data, if any, as an object.
   * @return Object|null
   */
// get the raw POST data
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
// this returns null if not valid json
$JSONSignedRequest = parse_signed_request($rawData);
$SignedRequestArray = json_decode($JSONSignedRequest);
if($SignedRequestArray["oauth_token"]) { 
    echo 'You are already signed in!';
}
else {
    if(isset($facebookLoginHtml)){ 
        echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
        echo "top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=

{*myappID*}&redirect_uri={https://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace/}&scope=publish_actions,
public_profile,user_friends,user_relationships,read_stream,publish_actions';"; 

        echo '</script>';        
    }
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  $secret = "*myappsecret*"; // Use your app secret here

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  // confirm the signature
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
     return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

StackOverflow won't let me post my settings as either an image or links. Most of the settings are links so I will try to add a comment with those.

Comment: App Settings - StackOverflow won't let me post images so I typed out the pertinent settings below.
Namespace:myappnamespace
App Domains: example.com
Canvas Page: https://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace
Canvas URL: http://example.com/
Secure Canvas URL: https://example.com/
Site URL: http://example.com/

Comment: What URL is actually being hit?